# How to detect if system has IPv6 enabled in a UNIX shell script?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, ipv6

I have a shell script, that is being executed on various POSIX environments such as Linux, Mac OSX or even Cygwin. The script needs to reliably detect if given system has IPv6 enabled. E.g. I can use at least IPv6 local loopback (::1).
So the question is:
How to detect if system has ipv6 enabled in a UNIX shell in a POSIX compatible way?

Comment: They all support IPv6. Do you mean to test whether they have it _enabled_? Or have a global address? Or a default route? Or something else?

Comment: Good point. Thank you. _Enabled_ IPv6 is the requirement - I edited the question.

Comment: IPv6 can be enabled for each device separately. Do I read your question correctly when I conclude that checking if IPv6 is enabled for the loopback device is what you are after?

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ I added that information to the question, the loopback device with ipv6 enabled is sufficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be tested by checking the existance of `/proc/net/if_inet6` as follows:

```
test -f /proc/net/if_inet6 && echo "IPv6 supported" || echo "IPv6 not supported"
```

I've tested it on Ubuntu, Mint, Raspberry PI and Bash shell in Windows, and it works in all these environments.

Comment: Thanks. On Mac OSX it incorrectly says "IPv6 not supported" - because '/proc/net/if_inet6' is Linux specific.

Comment: What about `sysctl -a | grep disable_ipv6`?

Comment: some other path in OSX that can be tested as an `||`ed test before the `&&` ? Good luck to all.

Comment: `ifconfig -a | grep inet6` returns something usable on Mac. `sysctl` doesn't.

Comment: An OS X/macOS specific test that works is `networksetup -listallnetworkservices | while read ns; do networksetup -getinfo "${ns}" | grep IPv6; done`. You could conditionally use that after something like `which sw_vers &> /dev/null ; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then …`.

Comment: This answer seems to check if ipv6 is _supported_. The question (and the answer I'm looking for) is whether it's _enabled_.

Comment: The question asks for a POSIX compatible solution, but this answer is Linux specific